# Absolute positioned div doesn't scroll; stays fixed on screen when other content scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to make my input range slider with id "slider_" stay fixed when scrolling on small screen sizes(when table contents overflow with scrollbar), that way it should scroll with the rest of content, though it just stays fixed on the screen and eventually escapes its parent div.

I've tried to nest the slider in another div with all sorts of positions on both o them, absolute, relative, sticky, fixed, static, but none of them worked out.

Here is some of my HTML

```
<div class="progress">

    <input id="slider_" type="range" min="0" max="1500" value="750" class="slider clicked slider-knob" disabled>

    <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar1" role="progressbar">
        <div class="progressBarZone">
            <span class="labels-singal">Down Trend</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar2" role="progressbar">
        <div class="progressBarZone">
            <span class="labels-singal">Strong Buy</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar3" role="progressbar">
        <div class="progressBarZone">
            <span class="labels-singal">Buy</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar4" role="progressbar">
        <div class="progressBarZone">
            <span class="labels-singal">Neutral</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar5" role="progressbar">
        <div class="progressBarZone">
            <span class="labels-singal">Sell</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar6" role="progressbar">
        <div class="progressBarZone">
            <span class="labels-singal">Strong Sell</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar7" role="progressbar">
        <div class="progressBarZone">
            <span class="labels-singal">Up Trend</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    height: inherit;
    background: transparent;
    width: 293px;
    overflow: visible;
}
.progress {
    overflow: visible;
    min-width: 283px;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: .75rem;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border-radius: .25rem;
}
```

I am willing to use jquery or js to fix this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.progress {
  position: relative;
}
```

You need to set a parent for the absolute element to stick to. The above should work.

Comment: No problem, remember every time you use absolute positioning there should be a parent somewhere with relative positioning, otherwise it will be relative to the body element.